# Neo4j/Cypher concurrent MERGE

Tags: neo4j, cypher, graph-databases, nosql

I wrote a simple test that executes concurrent `MERGE` requests and found that on empty database multiple nodes created although I expect unique node.

```
    [Test]
    public void ConcurrentNodeMerge()
    {
        // act
        Parallel.ForEach(Enumerable.Range(1, 10), index =>
        {
            client.Cypher
                .Merge("(n:Node)")
                .Set("n.Index = COALESCE(n.Index, '') + ' ' + {index}")
                .WithParam("index", index.ToString())
                .ExecuteWithoutResults();
        });

        // assert
        var result = client.Cypher
            .Match("(n:Node)")
            .Return<string>("n.Index")
            .Results;

        Assert.That(result.Count(), Is.EqualTo(1));
    }
```

I always end up with two nodes with index field like below

```
Index   8 3 7 5 2 10 6 1
Index   4 3 7 9 5 2 10 6 1
```

I expect to have one node with latest index executed.

**Note** I used .NET Neo4jClient

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume you don't have a constraint on the :Node(index) property.

```
CREATE CONSTRAINT ON (n:Node) ASSERT n.Index IS UNIQUE;
```

`MERGE` is not mean to guarantee uniqueness, it is guaranteed **ONLY** with a unique constraint.

Answer (score 1):

To explain why you are getting duplicates: concurrent `MERGE blah` operations are subject to a [race condition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Race_condition#Software) wherein each instance of the operation detects that `blah` does not yet exist, causing each to go ahead and create `blah`.

The way to avoid this situation is by using [uniqueness constraints](http://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/#_using_unique_constraints_with_merge), as illustrated by @ChristopheWillemsen.

Comment: Noting for future readers, the race condition was a result of a bug in some Neo4j versions (< 3.0.9 for 3.0.x versions, and < 3.1.2 for 3.1.x versions) and has since been fixed. The intent always was for locking guarantees so MERGE couldn't create duplicate nodes.